# possible to see where visitors are moving their mouse on website using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i know that there are websites which can detect where the mouse is moving on the screen on a website, and then display a movie of that visit. like robotreplay or clicktale.

how do they do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `onmousemove` event handler to capture the mouse move. Than you can read the x and y coordinates of the mouse cursor:

```
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = e.x + ":" + e.y;
};
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how i could convert this information into a movie? i would be running this on a php page.

Comment: Just record this data (I’d use a fixed period of time for recording, so that not every little movement is recorded). Then you can replay it. But I’m afraid that you cannot move the actual cursor but just a cursor replacement (an image of a cursor).

Comment: thanks, do you know the function on how to move an image across the screen from  one pixel to another pixel?

Comment: Position the element absolute and then move it around the screen with the `top` and `left` CSS properties.

Comment: Clicktale is one great tool for analytics.. because you can see the user experience on your website.

Answer (score 0):

The [mousemove](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onmousemove.asp) event.